# How I can make multiple navigation drawer activities in one project?

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I can't able to make multiple navigation drawer activities within one project.

Comment: Check here for how to get answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple navigation group and then hide show the group by its id according to your condition

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/group_feature"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/navdrawer_item_map"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_map"
            android:title="@string/navdrawer_item_map"/>

    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group_settings"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/navdrawer_item_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_settings"
            android:title="@string/navdrawer_item_settings"/>

    </group>
</menu>
```